# Good asset packager for HTML templates?

Tags: html, templates, underscore.js

I'm writing a web app that's complicated enough that it needs a large family of HTML templates (specifically they're underscore templates, but that part doesn't really matter).

I really want to be able to write template files that look like the following:

```
fooTemplate:
<div class="foo">
   <div class="bar"><%=name %></div>
</div>
```

And have it turn all of my template files into a single JS file that looks like this:

```
window.templates = {}
...
templates.fooTemplate = '<div class="foo"><div class="bar">...</div>';
```

Ideal properties:

- Has some way to specify the name of each template
- Strips unnecessary whitespace from all template files
- Concatenates all template files into a single, monolithic JS file
- Watches a directory and auto-updates when files change

Is there anything out there does does any of these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're unlikely to find a comprehensive solution that does everything you list, there will inevitable be "some assembly required" (if not, I'd love to hear about it).

- In the Rails world, [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) will do a lot of what you describe. It seems quite tightly coupled to Rails though, but I'm no Rails expert so I can't advice on how difficult it is to (ab)use with a different stack.
- In the Django world, there's [django-asset-packager](http://code.google.com/p/django-assetpackager/), but it only mentions CSS/Javascript.
- It's probably not too much work to roll your own based on [wr](https://github.com/guard/guard) or [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) for directory watching combined with Make/Rake/Paver/Cake/Ant tasks to process your templates. I did an ad-hoc solution along those lines once and it didn't even consume half a working day.
- You might also find some inspiration in [capt](https://github.com/bnolan/capt).